# aliases are not stored in zsh history

Tags: shell, zsh

Whenever I execute a command using an alias, this command is not stored in the shell's command history.

So if I run `history` these commands do not appear in the list.

Nor do they appear when I press `CTRL + r` for reverse searching the command history.

When I press the keyboard's arrow up for scrolling through the last commands, I will see an aliased command only if it was the last command I ran. Other aliased commands are will not be displayed.

For example:

```
$ cd my-repo
$ gs # an alias to git status
$ history
```

Outputs the following:

```
 2374  cd my-repo
```

(the gs command is not displayed)

A few notes:

1. gs is only an example. The issue is far more annoying in more complex commands since I have to retype them all over again instead of executing them from history (e.g. `k get pods | grep <pod_name>`, where k=kubectl).
2. gs is defined so: `alias gs=' git status'`.
3. I also have a few functions in ~/.alias, e.g.:

   ```
   mkcd () {
     mkdir -pv $1
   ```

   For some reason, `mkcd` (or any other function in the alias file) is included in the history.
4. I do not mind if it prints out `gs` or expands to `git status`, I'll take any of the two...
5. I am using zsh with oh-my-zsh on macOS (Monterey). My shell aliases are defined in ~/.alias which is sourced in ~/.zshrc (source ~/.alias).
6. This happens both in iTerm2 and in the default Mac terminal.

Thank you for taking the time to help :-)

Comment: Every command you type in the shell is put in the history. There is no relationship to the kind of command (alias, builtin, whatever...). There are tricks where you can modify the behaviour (for instance using a hook function to catch each command and remove it from the history based on certain conditions), but you have to actively do something, to achieve such a non-standard behaviour. What I'm missing from your question is the description of what steps we can perform to reproduce the behaviour which you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that your example alias is exactly what you have in your `~/.alias` file.
So you have aliases like this (notice the space character in front of `git` command):

```bash
alias gs=' git status'
```

There is an shell option called `HIST_IGNORE_SPACE` which is doing exactly what you are experiencing - in short it will not add command to the history when it starts with space character. Example:

```
echo 'This command will make it to the history.'
 echo 'This poor command will be forgotten.'
```

You can check your current options using `setopt` or specifically:

```bash
setopt | grep 'histignorespace'
```

So there are two ways how you can fix this - either by fixing your aliases to not start with space or, If you really don't want this functionality at all, by unsetting it in your `~/.zshrc` like this:

```
unsetopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE
```

Comment: What a nasty bug. Also, btw. what is this zsh behavior for? Why not store commands beginning with a space inside the history?